Problem understanding proof about total derivatives
I don't understand some steps in a proof that shows a function $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable when its partial derivatives exist and are continuous. The proof fixes a point $(a,b)\in U$ and shows $f$ is differentiable there.
I understand the beginning of the proof but some steps really confuse me. At one point the proof arrives at this equation:
$$f(x,y) = f(a,b) + (\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)(x-a) + (\partial_2 f)(a,d_y)(y-b).$$
Here $(x,y)$ is an arbitrary point in an open ball $B\in U$ with $(a,b)\in B$, the point $c_{x,y}$ is between $a$ and $x$, and $d_y$ is a point between $y$ and $b$. I understand how they got here so no problems so far. Then they take the limit of this equation, letting $(x,y)\to (a,b)$. Using the continuity of $\partial_1 f$ and $\partial_2 f$ they get:
$$(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)(x-a) = (\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a) + o(|x-a|)$$
$$(\partial_2 f)(a,d_y)(y-b) = (\partial_2 f)(a,b)(y-b) + o(|y-b|)$$
when $(x,y)\to (a,b)$. This one confuses me already. I get that because of continuity $(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y) \to (\partial_1 f)(a,b)$ when $(x,y)\to (a,b)$. But how do they suddenly arrive at this Little-o equation? I mean, we're taking a limit in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but suddenly the part inside the Little-o cares only about $x$, while the $y$ is still in the equation too. After that it gets even worse. From the previous two equations they instantly go to:
$$f(x,y)=f(a,b)+(\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a)+(\partial_2 f)(a,b)(y-b)+o(||(x,y)-(a,b)||).$$
This step I can't even begin to understand. I tried applying the limit definition of Little-o but it gets me nowhere. Could someone explain how they arrive at these Little-o equations using the definition of Little-o? I've studied other proofs of this theorem and they were never a problem but thiss Little-o stuff just seems to be beyond me.

Oh dear, I'm so sorry. You are correct of course. Just edited it.

Going back to the definition of $o()$, $$(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)(x-a) = (\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a) + o(|x-a|)$$
actually means
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)}\frac{(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)(x-a)-(\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a)}{(x-a)}=0,  $$
i.e. $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} (\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)-(\partial_1 f)(a,b)=0. $$
Why is this true? $c_{x,y}$ is between $a$ and $x$. In particular $|c_{x,y}-a|<|x-a|$.
By continuity of $\partial_1 f$, for all $\epsilon>0$ given, exists $\delta>0$ subject to,
$$ |x-a|<\delta, |y-b|<\delta\implies  |(\partial_1 f)(x,y)-(\partial_1 f)(a,b)|<\epsilon.  $$
For all $(x,y)$ with $|x-a|<\delta$, $|y-b|<\delta$, we also have $|c_{x,y}-a|<|x-a|<\delta$,
which leads to $$|(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)-(\partial_1 f)(a,b)|<\epsilon. $$
This proves $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} (\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)-(\partial_1 f)(a,b)=0. $$
Similarly $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} \partial_2f(a,d_y)-\partial_2f(a,b) =0. $$
We have the estimation
\begin{align*}
& |f(x,y)-f(a,b)- (\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a)-(\partial_2 f)(a,b)(y-b)|\\
=&\ |(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)(x-a) + (\partial_2 f)(a,d_y)(y-b)-(\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a)-(\partial_2 f)(a,b)(y-b)  |
\\ \le\ & |(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)(x-a)-(\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a)|  +|(\partial_2 f)(a,d_y)(y-b)-(\partial_2 f)(a,b)(y-b)|
\\=\ & |(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)-(\partial_1 f)(a,b)|\cdot |x-a|+|\partial_2f(a,d_y)-\partial_2f(a,b)|\cdot |y-b|.
\end{align*}
By our previous estimation, given $\epsilon>0$, we can select $\delta>0$, subject to if $|x-a|<\delta$, $|y-a|<\delta$ then
$$|(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)-(\partial_1 f)(a,b)|<\epsilon ,|\partial_2f(a,d_y)-\partial_2f(a,b)|<\epsilon.  $$
Then
\begin{align*}
& |f(x,y)-f(a,b)- (\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a)-(\partial_2 f)(a,b)(y-b)|
\\ \le\ & |(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)-(\partial_1 f)(a,b)|\cdot |x-a|+|\partial_2f(a,d_y)-\partial_2f(a,b)|\cdot |y-b|\\
\le\ &  \epsilon|x-a|+\epsilon|y-b|\\ \le&\  \epsilon\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}+\epsilon\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}=2\epsilon\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}.
\end{align*}
We conclude $|f(x,y)-f(a,b)- (\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a)-(\partial_2 f)(a,b)(y-b)|$ is indeed $o(\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2})$,
as desired.

I started writing this before Asigan's excellent answer, but I did spend a bit of time on this so I'll leave mine still.
EDIT: I've added an explanation for the second-to-last equality in the calculation at the very end.
Everything becomes clearer once you remember that convergence to $0$ is the same as $o(1)$, i.e.:
$$u(x) \to 0 \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\, u(x) = o(1)$$
which has this as a corollary:
$$u(x) \to \ell \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\, u(x) = \ell + o(1)$$
and that $o$ is a multiplicative notation, i.e.:
$$u(x) = o(v(x)) \,\,\Longrightarrow\,\, u(x)w(x) = o(v(x)w(x))$$
The formula $o(w(x)) = o(|w(x)|)$ is also the reason why absolute values can appear out of left field, but it's more minor than the former formulae. It's more "aesthetic" to try to have a positive quantity in the $o$ I suppose.
What's most important to understand though is that there's always something implied when writing $o$ without a subscript, that is, it's unamibiguous what limit is considered as taken.
Going back to the notation from your question, $o(|x - a|)$ by itself in the context it is in doesn't mean that what's in the small oh behaves only depending on how small $|x-a|$ is. It's even clearer if you consider "$o(1)$" by itself, expression in which you can't even infer the variable, let alone the limit, from the content of the parentheses...
For example, let's look at the following expression:
$$u(x,y) := |x-a|^2 + |y - b||x - a|$$
There are then multiple possible valid interpretations:

$u(x,y) = o_{\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| \to 0}(1)$, because if both $|x-a|$ and $|y-b|$ tend to $0$ then $u(x,y) \to 0$, which is the same as saying it is $o(1)$;
$u(x,y) = |x - a|^2 + o_{|y-b| \to 0}(1)$, because if $|x-a|$ is fixed then only the rightmost term in the definition of $u(x,y)$ matters. The $o$ depends on $x$ though, so that if we had looked at
$$v(x,y) = |x-a|^2 + \frac{|y-b|}{|x-a|}$$
instead, then $v(x,y) = |x - a|^2 + o_{|y-b| \to 0}(1)$ again yet $v(x,y) \neq o_{\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| \to 0}(1)$.

Anyway, instead of boring you even more with such details, let's get back to the question.
In the paragraph above, it should have been clear that the answer to this part:

I mean, we're taking a limit in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but suddenly the part inside the Little-o cares only about $x$, while the $y$ is still in the equation too.

is simply that the dependence on $y$ is still there but "hidden", since a lot of authors will not write the taken limit and instead rely on the reader to infer which limit should be there as the subscript of the $o$, like what I've done at the start, mostly to simplify notation.
There only remains to see how these formulae are derived the way they are derived, but it's pretty simple based on my first sentences.
Indeed:
$$(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y) \xrightarrow[\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| \to 0]{} (\partial_1 f)(a,b) \,\,\Leftrightarrow\,\, (\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y) = (\partial_1 f)(a,b) + o_{\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| \to 0}(1)$$
so that:
$$\begin{split}(\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)(x-a) &= (x-a)\left((\partial_1 f)(a,b) + o_{\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| \to 0}(1)\right)\\
&= (\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a) + o_{\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| \to 0}(|x-a|)\end{split}$$
The one with $o(|y-b|)$ is dealt with in the same manner, which then yields:
$$\begin{split} f(x,y) &= f(a,b) + (\partial_1 f)(c_{x,y},y)(x-a) + (\partial_2 f)(a,d_y)(y-b)\\
&= f(a,b) + (\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a) + o_{\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| \to 0}(|x-a|)\\
&\quad + (\partial_2 f)(a,b)(y-b) + o_{\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| \to 0}(|y-b|)\\
&= f(a,b) + (\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a)\\
&\quad + (\partial_2 f)(a,b)(y-b) + o_{\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| \to 0}(\max(|x-a|, |y-b|))\\
&= f(a,b) + (\partial_1 f)(a,b)(x-a)\\
&\quad + (\partial_2 f)(a,b)(y-b) + o_{\|(x,y) - (a,b)\| \to 0}(\|(x,y) - (a,b)\|)\end{split}$$
where the last equality uses the fact that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are equivalent to each other, thus in particular equivalent to the $\sup$-norm.
As for the second-to-last equality, it is a consequence of the fact that $\frac{s}{\max(s, t)} \leq 1$, so that an $o_{\max(s,t) \to 0}(s)$ is an $o_{\max(s,t) \to 0}(\max(s,t))$ (but the reverse is not true!).
